# Save and access class list in C#

Tags: c#, class, oop, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application in Xamarin.Forms that should allow a new movie to be added to a list by calling AddCartList. I am also trying to access each element of the list.

I have a class that stores movie information:

```
public class Movie
{
    public string movieTitle { get; set; }
    public string movieReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public int movieDuration { get; set; }
    public double movieRentalPrice { get; set; }
    public string movieRentType { get; set; }

    public Movie(string mtitle, string mdate, int mtime, double mprice, string type)
    {
        movieTitle = mtitle;
        movieReleaseDate = mdate;
        movieDuration = mtime;
        movieRentalPrice = mprice;
        movieRentType = type;
    }
}
```

This creates a list of movies that the user has selected to rent:

```
class MoviesRentCart
{
        public List<Movie> movieRentList;
        public MoviesToRent()
        {
            movieRentList = new List<MovieRent>();
        }

        public static MoviesToRent addCartList(string title, string date, int duration, double price, string type)
        {

            MoviesToRent movieList = new MoviesToRent();

            Movie newMovie = new Movie(title, date, duration, price, type);

            movieList.movieRentList.Add(newMovie);

            return movieList;
         }
}
```

My application allows the user to select a movie to rent, and then a prompt asks whether the user wishes to rent another movie at the same time. If the user responds with yes, then the current movie is added to the list:

```
MoviesToRent.AddCartList(this.title.Text, this.release_date.Text, this.run_time.Text, this.total.Text, this.type.Text);
```

Then, the previous page is displayed. When the user selects another movie to be added, the next page (the same page as where the movie was added to the list) should display the details of all movies that the user has selected to rent (in the list).

```
var moviesToRent = new MoviesToRent();
string movie_info = "";
foreach (MovieRentCart movie in moviesToRent.movieRentList)
{
        movie_info = movie_info + "\n" + movie.movieTitle + " (" + movie.movieReleaseDate + ") [" + movie.movieDuration + " minutes]";            
 }
 this.movie_details.Text = movie_info;
```

However, this does not display anything. What am I doing wrong? Movies should be added to the list and should be displayed by iterating through the list.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the code you have posted:

1. In your last code sample, you are creating a new instance of the MoviesToRent class. This new instance will always an empty list movieRentList, because you instantiate that to an empty list in the constructor.
2. The addCartList method should not be creating a new instance of itself, and this return value does not seem to get used in the code that you have posted. Does it really make sense to make this method static?

If I understand your question correctly, you need to keep a reference to the movies added to the movieRentList.

The quickest fix would be to make the whole class static:

```
public static class MoviesRentCart
{
        public static List<Movie> movieRentList;

        public static void addCartList(string title, string date, int duration, double price, string type)
        {
            Movie newMovie = new Movie(title, date, duration, price, type);

            movieRentList.Add(newMovie);
         }
}
```

Another approach would be to not make the addCartList be a static method and then share the instance of MoviesToRent between screens:

```
public class MoviesRentCart
{
        public List<Movie> movieRentList = new List<Movie>();

        public void addCartList(string title, string date, int duration, double price, string type)
        {
            Movie newMovie = new Movie(title, date, duration, price, type);

            movieRentList.Add(newMovie);
         }
}
```

You can store a link to this instance on the App page if you are using Xamarin.Forms, or you can pass it as a parameter to other pages that require the data.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding solution 1, attempting to call addCartList causes the application to break when I use this line: `MoviesRentCart.AddCartList(this.title.Text, this.release_date.Text, this.run_time.Text, this.total.Text, this.type.Text);`

Comment: @user10292318 1) The static version is bad practice and should not have been suggested. 2) If your version of his suggestion doesn’t work, you have to show your version of the code and also say what the error is. What you’re saying is “I have an error that’s a secret in some code that I won’t show you” — naturally, nobody can help you with that.